# View not resizing to screen size 3.5"/4"

Tags: ios, constraints

I have a view that I have set fixed leading/trailing space on its subviews. As I change the simulated metrics size to 3.5" or 4", the view resizes correctly. However, if I leave the simulated metric at 3.5" and run it on a 4" simulator, it doesn't fill the screen. Likewise, if I the simulated metric at 4" and run it on the 3.5" simulator, it gets cut off. I think it is because my view is missing constraints setting its width the window size, but I can't seem to find how to set these.

Comment: did you ever find an answer for this? I'm having the exact same issue